# How can I achieve this design in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I need to achieve the following design for these buttons

[image]

I have all the images.
The left round images with pressed state and normal
The button text background images but they are a rectangle shape.

I am using a linear layout and table layout 
This is my XML code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/stbk"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/scttransband" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/acc" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accountButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="My Account" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scttransband" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/locateButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Locate Branches &amp; ATM" />
    </TableRow>
```

This is the output I get

[image]

How do I cut the left corners for the background and also how do I make the pressed states so that both background and left Image changes plus the text color also changes?

Comment: Consider using clipdrawable..

Comment: Can you give me an example for it?

Comment: Well there's a very good example here
http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/
See if it helps you.

Comment: Just remove the padding from your button its occupying more space. And besides using table layout i suggest you to use `FrameLayout` it will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: @GrIsHu an example will be much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

I have written sample code for only single item..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="YOUR_COLOR"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="YOUR_TEXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="YOUR_CIRCLE_IMAGE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help this code..!!!